# Как узнать количество всех пользователей в discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я про бывал все способы и нечего не работает.
Прошу вас `скажите` как узнать `количество пользователей с помощью discord.py` `поэтапно`.

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко то получи список всех участников и посчитай с помою len(). Или же можно циклом

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def user_count(ctx):
    number = 0
    for member in members:
        number += 1
        print(f"{number}. \nName: {member.name}\nID: {member.id}\nDiscriminator: {member.discriminator}\nStatus: {member.status}\n")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: ваш код не работает